# Add encrypted variables to travis.yml and push to open source project

Tags: git, encryption, amazon-s3, open-source, travis-ci

I have been contributing to open source project & in one of the issues, I have to upload a folder to AWS S3. I have created an amazon aws account and everything is working.

But I am not able to find a way to correctly encrypt the credentials in the travis.yml file & make a pull request. I am using travis gem to encrypt the variables but is giving me an error that the repository is not known.

Also I read somewhere that the pull request containing sensitive information are not allowed from the forks of that project.

Please guide me on how to do this task!